# Cloning a private Github repo using a script

Tags: python, gitpython

How to clone a private repository from Github using python?

I found some good information about git and python, but I started learning python few days back.

Comment: What prohibits you from invoking "git clone ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library, [`libgit2`](https://github.com/libgit2), which enables git to be used as a shared library more helpful to your cause is the python binding's [`pygit`](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2).

To answer your question using `pygit` to clone a repo:

```
>>> from pygit2 import clone_repository
>>> repo_url = 'git://github.com/libgit2/pygit2.git'
>>> repo_path = '/path/to/create/repository'
>>> repo = clone_repository(repo_url, repo_path) # Clones a non-bare repository
>>> repo = clone_repository(repo_url, repo_path, bare=True) # Clones a bare repository
```

You can view the repository based docs [here](http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html)

Comment: to make it clear, i want to make a python script that will clone a github private repository to my pc, i just want to find how to do it and a guide to it

Comment: @user3914163 In this case the simplest way is to simply call the git binary from python, as Messa wrote.

Comment: How do you authenticate with that? The question was about a private repo, right?

Answer (score 5):

Just run the `git` command with [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["git", "clone", ...])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two cents since there's no answer yet to the repo being private. The way I usually do it is I create a special SSH key pair for the script and upload the public one to GitHub (or whatever hosting you're using).

You can have the script use the private key by running:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i private_key_file' git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygit2
repo_url = 'git://github.com/libgit2/pygit2.git'
repo_path = '/path/to/create/repository'
callbacks = pygit2.RemoteCallbacks(pygit2.UserPass("<your-personal-token>", 'x-oauth-basic'))
repo = pygit2.clone_repository(repo_url, repo_path, callbacks=callbacks)
```